# How to navigate to next page with scrapy (web scraping)

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract quotes from https://www.goodreads.com/quotes. It seems that I am only getting the first page and the next page part is not working. 
Here is my code:

```py
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.goodreads.com/quotes'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):

        for quote in response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            yield {
                'quoteText': quote.xpath(".//div[@class ='quoteText']").extract_first()
            }

        next_page=response.css("a").xpath("@href").extract()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_link=response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: There's 100 pages so I suggest putting them all in start_urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the `href` of the next page's link. 
Use this for getting next page URL:

```
next_page=response.css("a.next_page::attr(href)").get()
```

You can read more about selectors here:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: Glad I could help